# Java error: <identifier> expected: "date"

Tags: java, class, final

I am into around 4 weeks of learning Java programming, and I am receiving                 this error: expected final date;

I am stuck on this error message, and don't want to continue creating the program till' I can figure it out. It has to be simple. Any ideas? I don't receive the error when I have the block below, but that's how I think my teacher wants it written as.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class project1Naja {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {  

  String firstName; // To hold first name
  String lastName; // To hold last name
  int hours; // Child's hours
  final date; // Date of Service
  final double RATE; // Hourly rate
  final double TAX_RATE; // Tax percentage
  int fee; // Cost before tax added
  int taxAmount; // Tax total
  double totalFee; // Fee including tax

  // Scanner created to read input.
  Scanner childCare = new Scanner(System.in);

  String firstName; // Input. Enter first name 
  System.out.print("Enter your first name: " );
  firstName = childCare.nextLine();

  String lastName; // Input. Enter Last name 
  System.out.print("Enter your last name: " );
  lastName = childCare.nextLine();

  String hours; // Input. Enter child's hours
  System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: " );
  hours = childCare.nextLine();

  String date; // Input. Enter child's hours
  System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: " );
  date = childCare.nextLine();

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here. At the top of the class, you have `date` declared as just `final`. Final is not a type, it means that the variable being declared cannot be changed. The correct initialization is this:

```
final String date;
```

Then at the bottom, you redefine `date` to be a `String`. So delete that line and just replace it with the code I put above, and it should work.

As a matter of fact, you do that with every variable. You are defining them multiple times. You only need to define them once:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class project1Naja {

     public static void main(String[] args) {  

         String firstName; // To hold first name
         String lastName; // To hold last name
         int hours; // Child's hours
         final String date; // Date of Service
         final double RATE; // Hourly rate
         final double TAX_RATE; // Tax percentage
         int fee; // Cost before tax added
         int taxAmount; // Tax total
         double totalFee; // Fee including tax

         // Scanner created to read input.
         Scanner childCare = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter your first name: " );
         firstName = childCare.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter your last name: " );
         lastName = childCare.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: " );
         hours = childCare.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: " );
         date = childCare.nextLine();      
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lawrence for the quick tips! I am into a 100 pages of this book, and still learning. I made the adjustment as you suggested, and received a different error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
         hours = childCare.nextLine();
                                   ^
1 error  ....So, I will see research that, and when you say that I am unnecessary defining the variables, are you referring to having that block above //Scanner  created to read input..that felt kind of unnecessary to me, but I thought thats how my teacher wanted it, so.. :)

Comment: Thanks again, Lawrence. I'm back in business!